# Android Notification arrives only when device is usb debug attached

Tags: android, adb, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have exactly the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706450/notification-message-only-shows-when-device-connected-to-usb).Android Notifications triggered by pending intent  works perfectly when device is attached with debugger but does not works after remove.The solution given in that problem does not works for me.

Code

```
public class MedicineReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int notificationId=0;
    private static int id=0;
    DataBase dataBase;

    public MedicineReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        if(id!=intent.getIntExtra("ID",-1))
        {
            notificationId++;
            id=intent.getIntExtra("ID",-1);
        }

        dataBase=new DataBase(context);
        if(dataBase.isOkay(id+""))
        {


            Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,Medicine_ItemActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("ID",intent.getIntExtra("ID",-1));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.medicine)
                            .setContentTitle("ঔষধ ")
                            .setContentText(createText(intent))
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000})
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            if (getBool(dataBase.getSound(id + ""))) {
                String source = dataBase.getSourcse(id + "");
                if(source.compareTo("DEFAULT")==0)
                {
                    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    mBuilder.setSound(uri);
                }
                else
                {
                    mBuilder.setSound(getURI(source, context));
                }
            }

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    Uri getURI(String  st,Context context)
    {
        File ringtoneFile = new File(st); //sd-card path/songname.mp3

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, getFileName(st));
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtoneFile.length());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        //  content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);


        Uri Ringtone1 = Uri.parse(st);
        //Insert it into the database
        Log.i("TAG", "the absolute path of the file is :"+
                ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(
                ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());




        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);
        System.out.println("uri=="+uri);
        Log.i("TAG","the ringtone uri is :"+newUri);
        return newUri;
    }

    String getFileName(String  st)
    {
        String []pathFile=st.split("/");
        return pathFile[pathFile.length-1];
    }
    boolean getBool(String st)
    {
        if(st.compareTo("true")==0)
        {
            return  true;
        }
        else
        {
            return  false;
        }
    }
    String createText(Intent intent)
    {
        String text="আপনার "+dataBase.getName(id+"")+" ঔষধটি ";
        if(intent.getStringExtra("MORNING")!=null)
        {
            text+="(সকালে";
        }
        if(intent.getStringExtra("NOON")!=null)
        {
            text+=",দুপুরে";
        }
        if(intent.getStringExtra("NIGHT")!=null)
        {
            text+=",রাতে";
        }
        text+=")খাওয়ার সময় হয়েছে।";
        return text;







    }

}
```

Manifest declaration

```
<receiver
            android:name=".Starting.Medicine.MedicineReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: How did you declare this BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: BTW: get rid of the _createText()_ in this current form. Use strings.xml instead

Comment: Manifest declaration added.

Comment: how is the `BroadcastReceiver` triggered? Is `onReceive()` being called when debugger not attached? Add logging and check logcat to be sure.